# Flutter upload image

Tags: flutter, image, get, flutter-web

Get Api Flutter dont working
I tried various methods, if the link is wrong, then it should at least be displayed json text in terminal
photo should be shown

```
Future<dynamic> getPhotoUrl(int profileID) async {
    print("get Photo url $profileID");
    var client = http.Client();
    var url = Uri.parse("$profileBaseUrl/api/v2/profiles/$profileID/photos");
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'APIVersion': '1',
      "Authorization": token,
    };

    var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (200 == response.statusCode) {
      return response.body;
    } else {

    }
    print("avatar url: $currentPhotoUrl");
  }
```

tried this and it doesn't work

```
Future<void> getPhotoUrl(int profileID) async {
    print("get photo url $profileID");
    var client = http.Client();

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Authorization": token
    };
    final http.Response response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse("$profileBaseUrl/api/v2/profiles/$profileID/photos"),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = responseBody["data"];
      if (data.length < 1) {}
      else {
        currentPhotoUrl.value = data[0]["content"][0]["medium"];
      }
    } else {
      throw WebSocketException("server error: ${response.statusCode}");
    }

    print("photos url: $currentPhotoUrl");
  }
```